# Is Future.wait trully asynchonous in Dart?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, future

I need to wait for many `Future` to complete their computation, a bunch of HTTP requests, I don't want to `await` all of them in order as this will result in each `Future` being evaluated in order, one after the other, kinda synchronously, which is wasteful as some `Future` might complete sooner than others.

I can't find in the docs of `Future.wait` is truly asynchronous, firing all the `Future` at the same time, or if its the same as calling them one after the other, waiting for the previous to complete to call the next.

In a nushell: I am looking for the best performant way to get the results of many HTTP requests in Dart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Future.wait` does await multiple futures in an asynchronous way, as in each of the futures is started independently of one another. By contrast, `Future.forEach` will loop through the list of futures and await on them in sequence.

For example, if you had the following list of futures:

```dart
var futures = [
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds, 3)).then((_) => print('1')),
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds, 2)).then((_) => print('2')),
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds, 1)).then((_) => print('3')),
];
```

Calling `Future.wait` on this list would result in the following output:

```dart
3 (after 1 second)
2 (after 2 seconds)
1 (after 3 seconds)
```

Whereas calling `Future.forEach` on the list would result in this:

```dart
1 (after 3 seconds)
2 (after 5 seconds)
3 (after 6 seconds)
```

This is because `wait` fires them all simultaneously then handles them as they all resolve while `forEach` fires them individually in order and waits for each one to resolve before going to the next one.

*(Here is the usual disclaimer that asynchronous programming is not the same thing as parallel programming, and that Dart is an inherently single-threaded language so true parallelism cannot be achieved with futures alone.)*

Answer (score 1):

If you check the implementation of the `Future.wait` method in:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/a75ffc89566a1353fb1a0f0c30eb805cc2e8d34c/sdk/lib/async/future.dart#L354-L443

You can actually see it goes through each `Future` in the input list and runs the `then` method which a method to be run when the `Future` completes:

```
      for (var future in futures) {
        int pos = remaining;
        future.then((T value) {
        ...
```

You could therefore say that all `Future` instances are "started" at the same time since each completed `Future` will end up checking if there are more futures to wait for.

However, please note that Dart is single threaded with a job queue behind the scene, so unless some of the work are done in `Isolate` instances, each job will end up running in serial. More details about this can be found here:

https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a

But yes, if you have a bunch if `Future`'s which can be handles in any order it makes sense to use the `Future.wait` method.

Comment: In my case I have a bunch of HTTP requests, so I think those will be deferred to the OS and Dart will not leave the code hanging waiting, once the OS marks the network transfer as completed, Dart's event loop should go back to that `Future` and queue it for completion.... at least that's how I understand that asynchronous model. So the idea is to have the fastest `Futures` returning first, and the slowest later, and not have a case where I need to wait for the slower to complete, to start then listening to the fast one.

Comment: In a nushell: I am looking for the best performant way to get the results of many HTTP requests in Dart.

Comment: There should really be a paragraph in this answer that explains the difference between "asynchronous" and "parallel". The second-to-last paragraph sort of touches on it but not in a very helpful or educational way.

Comment: I don't have fully knowledge how Dart are scheduling web requests but I would guess it is done in a way so multiple requests are allowed to be sent and waiting for each request to be completed. If performance is important, it would make sense to test the behavior and see if things works as expected.

Comment: I want to add that the whole discussion about "asynchronous" and "parallel" can be really complicated if you are digging enough into the topic. I don't feel I have the necessary skills to make a short description about the difference in a Dart context. :)